# How do you use Keypress package with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, keypress

I'm trying to use keypress.js with meteor so that anytime i press a letter I am getting that letter displayed.

```
Template.letters.events({
var listener = new Keypress.Listener();
Session.set("letter", Session.get("listener") + 1);
}
```

});

I'm pretty sure this is not how I am suppose to do this..any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need Keypress.js for this. Seems like that library is for detecting specific, complex key combinations. You should be able to do this:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  Session.set('letter', String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```